# HTML Input type image won't redirect upon click?

Tags: javascript, html, image, redirect, imagebutton

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
<input type="button" name="btnHello" value="Hello" onclick="Test();"/>
```

and here is the JS function:

```
function Test() {
  window.location.href = "Page2.aspx";
}
```

When I click my Hello button, it redirects to Page2.aspx like expected. But when I change my button to an image button:

```
<input type="image" src="images/myimage.jpg" name="btnHello" onclick="Test();"/>
```

It no longer works. The page posts back, but its more like a refresh. I can put an alert in the JS function to see that it is getting called, but I'm not sure why the redirect doesn't work? Has anyone ever experienced this?

I know its probably something stupid, but I'm stumped.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `return false` from the event handler to prevent the default action.

However, since you don't want it to postback in the first place, you might as well use an ordinary `<img />` instead of an `<input />`.

Comment: Thank you. Returning false from my JS function did not seem to have any effect, but using the <img> tag does seem to work!

Comment: @lloydhanneman16: That's because you never use the function's return value.  You need to return false from the **handler**.  (`onclick="return false"`)

Comment: Yep that did it, I changed it so onclick="return Test();" and that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The redirect is getting cancelled because you are doing a postback.  Add return false; after the function test();

e.g

```
onclick="test();return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `img` tag:

```
<img src="images/myimage.jpg" name="btnHello" onclick="Test();"/>
```

Comment: The point is to have it as a more semantic `<input>` element.

Comment: @Truth but the OP does not want the input to do anything anyway, might as well use an `img` tag

Comment: There are exactly 0 cases where when clicking an `<img>` tag should do anything. Either it should be a(n image) link, or an `<input>`.

Answer (score -1):

input type image does not have a onclick event. You need to use the img tag instead.
    `<img onclick="Test();">`

Comment: It does have an onclick event, like I said in my original question, I can put an alert statement in the JS function and it will get called. The problem was that the postback was cancelling the redirect.